# Vim repeat blocks of text(code) with parameters

Tags: vim

Many times I have come across situations where I need to repeat a code template several times, usually it's boiler plate code. The only thing that would change between different blocks is a few parameter names, which are peppered throughout the block. Is it possible to automate this in Vim without much effort?

Comment: Neosnippet or Snipmate seem to be what you're looking for. That said, tool recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.